# How to directly read a string in std::string from a file in C++?

Tags: c++

How to directly read a string in `std::string` from a file in C++?

The examples I saw all use `char xx[200];`

Comment: `filestream >> someString;`

Comment: Rather depends on the structure of the file.

Comment: Just use `std::getline` from the `<string>` header. If you instead use the `>>` operator you will get the next whitespace-separated "word", not the next line.

Comment: What kind of string do you want to read exactly? A single word? A whole line? The whole file? Each one is approached differently, so please clarify your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Use like, `File_object>>string_variable;`

Answer (score 0):

The `<string>` realized a `>>` operator, that can read a string into `std::string` directly from `std::istream`.